# Как в PyQt5 сделать ввод в lineEdit типом int?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit

делаю программу, которая будет переводить десятичное число в двоичное.

Вот код:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from binar import Ui_Dialog

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

def binarik():
    num = ui.lineEdit.text()
    newNum = ''
    while num > 0:
        newNum = str(num % 2) + newNum
        num //= 2
    ui.label_4.setText({newNum})

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( binarik )
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Юзер вводит число в верхнее поле и получает результат в области справа от кнопки (там TextLabel)

[image: Интерфейс]

После выполнения кода появляется ошибка:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Замените QLineEdit на QSpinBox. Для получения значения можно использовать его метод value() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qspinbox_widget.htm

Comment: `num =  int(ui.lineEdit.text())` ,  но правильное решение предложил @AlexanderChernin

Comment: @S.Nick, пробовал - появляется новая ошибка
` 
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel.set
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel.setText(set)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel.setText(str) 
`

Comment: замените `ui.label_4.setText({newNum})` на `ui.label_4.setNum({newNum})`

Comment: @S.Nick, не помогло, появляется подобная ошибка:
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel.setNum' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel.setNum(set)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel.setNum(float)
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel.setNum(int) 
Если же убрать ```num = int(ui.lineEdit.text())```, то будет самая первая ошибка с TypeError.

Comment: замените ui.label_4.setText({newNum}) на ui.label_4.setText(newNum)

Comment: @S.Nick, помогло, огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, но в следующий раз публикуйте пожалуйста все модули ( в.т.ч и binar.py) для быстрого решения проблемы.

Comment: @S. Nick, хорошо, учту, пока новичок здесь.